# Image as kernel of cokernel and epimorphism in category theory

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

I am studying [Vakil's notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf), Section 1.6.3, on the concept of abelian categories.

A **kernel** of a morphism $f: B\rightarrow C$ is a map $i: A\rightarrow B$ such that $f\circ i=0$, and that is universal with respect to this property. Diagramatically:

[image]

A **cokernel** is defined dually by reversing the arrows.

The **image** of a morphism $f: A\rightarrow B$ is defined as $\text{im}(f)=\ker(\text{coker (f)})$.

It is mentioned as a fact that

> For a morphism $f: A\rightarrow B$, $A\rightarrow \text{im}(f)$ is an epimorphism. I will show an equivalent statement: $f: A\rightarrow B$ is an epimorphism if $\text{im}(f)=B$.

Here is my effort so far to show it.

We have the following diagram:
[image]

$e: B\rightarrow C$ is the cokernel of $f$, $i: B\rightarrow B$ is the kernel of the cokernel, hence the image of $f$. To show $f$ is an epimorphism, suppose that $\phi\circ f=0$ for some $\phi: B\rightarrow D$. We need to show that $\phi=0$.

We see that $\alpha\circ e\circ i=\phi\circ i=0$. My question is, when we say $\text{im}(f)=B$, does it implicitly imply that $\text{im}(f)$ is the identity map $\text{id}_B: B\rightarrow B$? If that is true, then I have $\phi=0$. Then the proof is done. If it is not, I don't know how to continue to show $\phi=0$.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you edit your diagram to denote the dotted $f$ by another letter, say $g$, it becomes easy to check that the statements are equivalent in case $\text{im } f = B$ is taken to mean $i = 1_B$. So for the purposes of the proof, you're fine to take it that way. It's hard to say there's a "correct" interpretation, since the statement constitutes an abuse of notation.

Comment: @Mr.Chip: Thank you for your comment. I put $f$ there since I think that map is unique, so it has to be $f$. But I see the abuse of notation there. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You can also show the way more useful statement: Every morphism factors as a coimage (cokernel of kernel) followed by an image (kernel of cokernel). Now remember that equalizers are mono and dually coequalizers are epi, hence kernels are mono and cokernels are epi.

Comment: @StefanPerko: Thank you! That is very enlightening.